# Meaning of a phrase "Let it be no more"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have a question about the phrase "Let it be no more" and when is possible to use it.

The context in which the phrase appears is:

> The process by which the widget creates its displayed HTML has been so far kept a mistery. **Let it be no more.**

Comment: In this case "Let it be no more" is basically "let it no longer be what I just affirmed it to be (i.e. kept a mystery)", so its a declaration that the author intends to change the process to remove the mystery (maybe). But "let" (I think) is technically third person verb with no clear referent, so it doesn't necessarily mean he intends to do anything; it could also be an expression of hope, like he hopes someone else will remove the mystery.

Comment: You can use it anytime it applies, that is. when you want to see a current state, practice, circumstance, etc. ("kept a mystery" in your example) replaced by its negation ("not kept a mystery").

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is a bit tricky in that it has an invisible piece: "Let it be [that way] no more". It is equivalent to "I want it to stop being [that way]". In the case of your example, "I want *the process* to stop being *a mystery*".

I assume the writer of your example continues the article by explaining the process further. In that case, the sentence means "I will now take action to stop *the process* from being *a mystery* anymore".

In other contexts, the writer/speaker may mean that they *hope* the thing will stop being that way, but that other people will help bring the change about. This is an outdated way to convey that thought though: it sounds like a king giving a command. Today, you're more likely to hear it in a formal prayer at church than from someone writing a blog post.

It is probably best to use that phrase only when it is very clear which noun "it" references, and what the invisible "that way" references. This probably also means keeping the phrase relatively separate, as the author of your example did.

Comment: Its used in math: Let X = 5.